# gRPC context on the client side

Tags: go, grpc

I am building a client/server system in go, using gRPC and protobuf (and with a gRPC gateway to REST).

I use [metadata](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/metadata) in the context on the server side to carry authentication data from the client, and that works perfectly well.

Now, I'd like the server to set some metadata keys/values so that the client can get them, alongside with the response. How can I do that? Using [SetHeader](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#SetHeader) and [SendHeader](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#SendHeader)? Ideally, I'd like every single response from the server to integrate that metadata (can be seen as some kind of [UnaryInterceptor](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#UnaryServerInterceptor), but on the response rather than the request?)

Here is the code for the [server](https://gitlab.com/pantomath-io/demo-grpc/blob/add-auth/server/main.go) and for the [client](https://gitlab.com/pantomath-io/demo-grpc/blob/add-auth/client/main.go).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found my way: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md

So basically, `grpc.SetHeader()` + `grpc.SendHeader()` and `grpc.SetTrailer()` are totally what I was looking for. On the client side, `grpc.Header()` and `grpc.Trailer()` functions need to be passed to the RPC call, and their argument is a `metadata.MD` object to be filled.

On the client side, define your receiving metadata:

```
var header, trailer metadata.MD
```

Then, pass it to the `SomeRPCCall()` unary RPC:

```
response, err := client.SomeRPCCall(
    context.Background(),
    proto.MyMessage{},
    grpc.Header(&header),
    grpc.Trailer(&trailer),
)
```

And now, you can check what's in your metadata:

```
for key, value := range header {
    fmt.Printf("%s => %s", key, value)
}

for key, value := range trailer {
    fmt.Printf("%s => %s", key, value)
}
```

On the server side, you can:

- force the data to be sent right after the RPC is received (but before it's processed):

  `grpc.SendHeader(ctx, metadata.New(map[string]string{"my-key": "my-value"}))`
- or set & send the metadata at the end of the RPC process (along with the `Status`):

  `grpc.SetTrailer(ctx, metadata.New(map[string]string{"my-key": "my-value"}))`